# How to center div vertically in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I started work with bootstrap 4 and trying to create some basic layout. According to the [bootstrap 4 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#vertical-alignment), I can align block elements vertically by applying class `align-items-center` to them.

I tried to do the a [basic example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JMvyJd) on codepen, but div's are not positioned on center vertically.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Bootstrap uses a 12 column layout system try changing col-md-4 to col-md-6 (assuming you want 2 columns).

Comment: @JonathanChaplin I changed col-md-4 to col-md-6, but this change affects only horizontal positions, while I'm looking for align these 2 div's to center vertically

Comment: Ok, you need to add w-100 and h-100 for full height and width on several elements. I'll post a solution below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to vertically center those elements set the height and width of html and body to 100%. Setting width & height to 100% makes an element take on the height of it's parent.

Next, set all the child elements accordingly. In bootstrap `width: 100%` is `w-100` and `height:100%` is `h-100`. Also, bootstrap uses a 12 column layout so change your class from `col-md-4` to `col-md-6`

Note: you could add w-100 and h-100 to html and body in your code for the same effect.

```
<style>
    html,body{
      width:100%;
      margin:0;
        height:100%;
    }
</style>

<div class="container w-100 h-100">
    <div class="row align-items-center h-100">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1 class="alert alert-primary">Vertical</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1 class="alert alert-success">Vertical</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```